# How to prompt save as option for user to download file using chrome?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, cross-browser

I have method that is downloading file whenever this method called it is working as expected, I just see difference in browser in IE user has option to save As file but in chrome it directly download the file , How can we have that feature in chrome so user can use Save as option while saving the file so they can name the file ?

ctrl.js

```
function deleteFile(filename){
    DitFactory.getFile(filename).then(function(response,$window){
        console.log('data for download', response);
        var data = JSON.stringify(response.data);
        var blob = new Blob([data], { type: 'text/plain;charset=utf-8' });
        FileSaver.saveAs(blob, 'server.log');
        socket.emit('stopRecording',$scope.filename);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are asking isn't possible. 
It's a user preference

[image]

ref: http://www.howtogeek.com/231002/how-to-change-the-chrome-download-folder-location/

The only thing you can do is letting the user rename `server.log` inside a input element or a `window.prompt` before saving

```
saveAs(blob, prompt('Filename?', 'server.log') || 'server.log');
```

Comment: I want user to select directory and save file with new name like IE.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation , i will go with your approach.

Answer (score -2):

Well, why dont you use regular confirm?

```
if (confirm('Save As a File?')) {

   FileSaver.saveAs(blob, 'server.log');
}
```